# Need help in displaying query output in text field: LWC javascript

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have the case object output in **result** variable. From result I am trying to get value for 2 field(Case Origin, Subject) and display that in 2 text box.

```
getCaserecord() {
        getDesciptionVal({ caseNo: this.caseNum })
            .then(result => {
                this.caseRec = result;
                this.error = undefined;

                if (this.caseRec) {
                    this.caseOrigin = 'Web'; //Hard coded value
                    this.caseSubject = 'This is case subject'; //Hard coded value
                }
                for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        console.log('Case Subject '+ result[i].Subject.data);
                        console.log('Case Origin '+ result[i].Origin.data);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.caseRec = undefined;
                this.error = error;
            })
    }

Apex Code:

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<case> getDesciptionVal(String caseNo)
    {
        List<Case> caseRec = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber, ContactId, AccountId, Subject, Description, Status,Origin 
                                FROM Case 
                               WHERE CaseNumber = :caseNo];
        return caseRec;
    }
```

I am getting "undefined" error in console.log. I need help in fixing this issue.

Comment: Please share the apex code for getDesciptionVal method.

Comment: @AnmolKumar I have updated the code.

Comment: Exactly, what is undefined here? can you share that as well?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to see the output.

Here is the updated console.log code.

```
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        console.log('Case Subject '+ result[i].Subject);
                        console.log('Case Origin '+ result[i].Origin);
                }
```